# is there any way to draw shapes with fingers over MAP BOX MAP for android studio

Tags: android, mapbox

I just want to draw shape with finger over MAP BOX map with android, But i cant find solution. is there any option to do it ?

Comment: can you have screen shoot

Comment: yes i have screenshot.    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FBMcZnhf5Ej3DNCu_UNlwIDhUXiZsr8T/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/pull/983

Answer (score 3):

see https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/pull/983 and https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/pull/983/files#diff-e3b54579502b42722d723bdc38541f57

Basically, you have a touch listener on the `MapView`. As the touching happens, you convert the touch point to actual map coordinates. You add that coordinate to a list of coordinates and then continually update the `LineLayer`'s GeoJSON with the new coordinate list. That's how the `LineLayer` gets updated as the map touching/drawing happens.

Because your screenshot in OP shows a polygon rather than looser finger drawing, there's also https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/dds/SatelliteLandSelectActivity.java (via https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/pull/868).

Comment: can you please provide me only finger draw activity so that i can use your code in my app.

Comment: i only want to draw over map and your project files are quite confusing to me.

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/5ac2a217c7ae08d5181033e30b9f223a250ffad6/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/query/FingerDrawActivity.java

Comment: FingerDrawActivity class is never used in this project. how can i implement FingerDrawAcitivity in my Project.